# How to use dynamic icon with google map chart

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I want to display a dynamic icon with google map chart

I had done this far

```
function putMaker(position,title,title_dis,number,icon_img,icon2)
{


     if (!isNaN(number)) var icon = "https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chst=d_bubble_icon_text_small&chld=ski|bb|"+number+"|FFFFFF|000000";


    else var icon = null;
    //icon= icon2;
     var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                      position: position,
                      map: map,
                      icon: icon,

                     });
     google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', function() {
                   infowindow.setContent(title_dis);
                   infowindow.open(map, this);
                   });
}
```

"icon2 is a `MarkerImage`"

This is perfect but the icon shown here is `ski`[image]

I want to replace this icon with another icon say `icon2`(created using `MarkerImage` api)
Any idea how to do this ?

Comment: Do you mean a default in the case where number is NaN?

Answer (score 0):

you need to change url of API      if (!isNaN(number)) var icon = "https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chst=d_bubble_icon_text_small&**chld=ski|bb|**"+number+"|FFFFFF|000000";

and replace "ski" to another from https://developers.google.com/chart/image/docs/gallery/dynamic_icons

eg: chld=maps_pin
or chld=camping|ADDE63

Comment: this has been deprecated since 2012